# Django rest fetch data from bridge model

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, active-model-serializers

I want to get all the user details and list of all the roles against the 
user details model
My Models

```py
class UserDetail(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                related_name='userdetail_user', default='111')
    cn = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    sn = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    u_id = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    display_name_cn = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    display_name_en = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    given_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    employee_number = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=True)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.given_name


class Role(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=True)
    last_updated = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=True)
    status = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class UserRole(models.Model):
    userdetail = models.ForeignKey(UserDetail, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                   related_name='userrole_userdetail')
    role = models.ForeignKey(Role, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    approver = models.ForeignKey(UserDetail, on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
                                 null=True,
                                 related_name='userrole_userdetail_approver')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=True)
    last_updated = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=True)
    status = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

My Serializers

```py
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'email')


class UserRoleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = UserRole
        fields = (
            'id', 'userdetail', 'role', 'approver', 'last_updated', 'status')
        depth = 1

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        representation = super(UserRoleSerializer, self).to_representation(
            instance)
        representation['userdetail'] = UserDetailSerializer(
            instance.userdetail).data
        representation['role'] = RoleSerializer(instance.role).data
        representation['approver'] = UserDetailSerializer(
            instance.approver).data
        return representation


class RoleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Role
        fields = ('id', 'title', 'description', 'last_updated', 'status')


class UserDetailSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = UserSerializer()
    roles = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = UserDetail
        fields = ('id', 'roles', 'user', 'cn', 'sn', 'u_id', 'display_name_cn',
                  'display_name_en', 'given_name', 'employee_number', 'email',
                  'last_login')

        lookup_field = 'u_id'

    def get_roles(self, obj):

        roles = UserRole.objects.filter(userdetail=obj)
        return roles
```

When I try to fetch all the user details it gives me an error 
"Object of type 'UserRole' is not JSON serializable".

I have already tried to serialize the list of object fetched inside get_roles method of UserDetailsSerializer but its no help

Comment: In UserDetailSerializer try: ```roles=UserRoleSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)```

Comment: @DovRine Already tried that it removes the error but still don't show any roles in the user_detail api

Comment: That's definitely the right way to serialize the roles. I would try eliminating everything and populating the user_detail_api response one piece at a time. If that's where you are now and roles is all that's left, then, I would make a very simple serializer that doesn't filter the roles, just to get them showing up. Once that works, replace the filtering. If you can't get the simple serializer working, the problem may be in the view.

Comment: Btw, you may also need to specify ```role=RoleSerializer()``` in UserRoleSerializer.

Comment: UserRoleSerializer references UserDetailSerializer which references UserRoleSerializer again (in my fix). As I mentioned earlier, I think that you need to simplify the serializers. I've had this problem when I've had to hack away at a problem that turned out to be more complex than I initially thought. Sometimes, rethinking the design of the data here will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Serializers, you have to replace

```
 roles = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)
```

With

```
userrole_userdetail = UserRoleSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
```

Its because your FK relation name must match the related name given in the model. Also in UserRoleSerializer you do not need the **to_representation** method.